# Add top k results to sklearn pipeline?

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I want to put my model in cloud, but it expects a single *joblib* file.
I have a model, which predicts the class (multiclass classification).
I currently use `np.argsort` and get my top `k` results.

How do I add another step in sklearn pipeline which takes the output from the model, so that a single pipeline gives me back ***top k*** results?

Because AFAIK, *joblib* can only dump a single pipeline with trained model.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do inheritance of `Pipeline` and add a method for getting the `top k` prediction using probabilities.

```
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
from sklearn.datasets import make_classification

X, y = make_classification(n_features=20, n_informative=15, n_classes=5)

class MyPipeline(Pipeline):
    def get_top_k(self, X, k=3):
        probs = self.predict_proba(X)
        return np.fliplr(np.argsort(probs, axis=1)[:, -k:])

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y,
                                                    random_state=42)
pipe = MyPipeline([('scalling', StandardScaler()),
                   ('logistic', LogisticRegression())])
pipe.fit(X_train, y_train)
pipe.get_top_k(X_test[:2, :])
```

Now dump the `pipe` object using `joblib`.

Comment: Hi thanks, but is there a way to rather inherit 'estimator' class (if it exists) and create top_k estimator, so that we could create a pipeline with that top_k as last element in that. Then while .fit(), other components could've done their job, while top_k wouldve just sat silently, but while .predict(), it wouldve jumped to action?

Comment: Inheriting `pipeline` is a more generaliazed solution. In my answer, it does what you want. It does all the transformation using the `predict_proba` output and then gives you the Top k classes for any classifier which supports `predict_proba`.